# gestures with new hammer.js is not working like before

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I just update hammer.js to newest version but after update I have error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

because

```
var fieldId = event.gesture.target.id.split('_')[0];
```

Gestures are working but how can I handle my fieldId in new hammer.js ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the API documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#event-object).
The `target` is (now) a direct descendant of the `event`. So you're probably looking for simply `event.target`.